# Wait of function result after context cancellation

Tags: go

I can't understand the logic of this example in [Go Concurrency Patterns: Context](https://blog.golang.org/context)

```
func httpDo(ctx context.Context, req *http.Request, f func(*http.Response, error) error) error {
    // Run the HTTP request in a goroutine and pass the response to f.
    c := make(chan error, 1)
    req = req.WithContext(ctx)
    go func() { c <- f(http.DefaultClient.Do(req)) }()
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        <-c // Wait for f to return.
        return ctx.Err()
    case err := <-c:
        return err
    }
}
```

Before that it is said that:

> The `Done` method returns a channel that acts as a cancellation signal
>   to functions running on behalf of the `Context`: when the channel is
>   closed, the functions should abandon their work and return.

It looks like the equivalent of awaiting of `<-c` only, without `case <-ctx.Done()` at all. So, what is the point?

Comment: So, you think, it's just an error in documentation?

Comment: It's just a very poorly conceived example.

Comment: @Flimzy aren't they completely separate though? `c` is returned by `f` whose implementation we don't have and which could be doing pretty much anything *after* `http.DefaultClient.Do(req)` returned, successfully or not. `ctx` signals the result of `http.DefaultClient.Do(req)` while `c` signals the result of `f(...)`. `f` could fail while `Do` could pass just fine, no?

Comment: @mkopriva: I guess you're right. `f` could be doing something interesting.

Comment: I think the writer was a bit lazy in the end, a few lines up he says ` It accepts a Context parameter ctx and returns immediately if ctx.Done is closed while the request is in flight.` => **returns immediately if ctx.Done is closed**. But in the final block of code you presented, that happens ONLY because we know that client.Do will return immediately, it is not hold strongly, pass it a dummy function that does not listen its context and the scheme falls. unclear.

Comment: @Flimzy although I do see now that in the article the closure that's passed in as `f` returns immediately if `Do` returns an error, which makes my previous comment less relevant. However what about the case where the context is cancelled, by the caller of the `Search` function, *after* `Do` successfully returned, if we don't listen to `ctx.Done` and `f` does it's job without error we would hit the `case err := <-c:` and `httpDo` would return `nil` instead of the `ctx.Err()` that would tell us why the *caller* cancelled the context.

Comment: @mkopriva: A good `f()` implementation would handle `ctx.Done()` even after `Do` returns, of course... but that's a bit of a tangent, and you have an otherwise valid point.  All in all: Bad example, IMO.

Comment: Yes, if f() will process ctx - all clear. But in current implementation, which is WithTimeout() illustration, it's unclear. The timeout is not a timeout.

Comment: @mkopriva I found it. It's handle it in the line  req = req.WithContext(ctx)

Answer (score 3):

The context may cancel the `Do` call. The `case <-ctx.Done()` unambiguously identify that this happened.

Indeed, we may assume that the `Do` call would then return a `nil` `http.Response`, and that the function `f` would then return an error when this happens. But we wouldn’t know why `f` received a `nil` `http.Response` as input argument.

The instruction `case err := <-c:` handles the case when the error is produced inside `f`.

Comment: Ok, but what if <-ctx.Done () is generated by a timeout or deadline, and f ends in a long time?

Comment: @goofinator with current code, client.Do will return asap. in some theoretical examples you might think about, this will hold the execution until a value can be popped out of c.

Comment: yes. That's what i mean. I think, that in example of WithTimeout usage, the f() should handle ctx too, so awaiting of it's result make sense. It is not necessary in current code, but makes example unclear. IMHO

Comment: @mh-cbon I get it. This is not obvious, but f () is called in the context of ctx. This is because the f function itself is fast, but it waits http.DefaultClient.Do () to complete, which is called using req, which was previously modified using req = req.WithContext (ctx). Thus, a long call can process Done () internally and immediately write something to channel "c". So, the client’s expectations regarding the timeout are fulfilled.

Answer (score 1):

It is not equivalent to awaiting `<-c` only. The example returns a different value (`ctx.Err()`) when the context is closed.

Comment: yeah, could be the correct explanation. But the example is confusing as client.Do will, i believe, return context cancelled error.

Comment: @mh-cbon: Yes, exactly. It will. See [here](https://play.golang.org/p/NYqHNzylxoF).

Comment: In that sense, yes. But if we consider this in terms of runtime? It turns out that the procedure will finish when it finishes and not earlier, what would timeouts not require? In addition, you can return ctx.Err () without waiting for <-c

Comment: @Flimzy thanks, added some more for new comers https://play.golang.org/p/KuNA_6GZ3z5